# Google map is disappearing after 5 sec

Tags: javascript

Please find the code snippet which i have used for develop the google map inside the div.

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <html>
  <body onload="initialize()"><script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?   key=ABCDEFG"     type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
          google.load("maps", "2.x");
          // Call this function when the page has been loaded
          function initialize() {
              var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));
              map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(16.9800, 81.7800), 13);
              map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
              map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
          }
          google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
        </script>
        <form id="f1">
              <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 400px"></div>
        </form>
      </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179788/google-maps-onclick-infowindow-disappear-after-refresh-cycle

Answer (score 0):

I tested your script in Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome, and it worked as it should.

You may have exceeded usage quota or you might be using a port that is not authenticated.

In the developer console(press F12) you might see an error that states: This site has exceeded its usage quota for Google Maps JavaScript API. See here for details on usage limits: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

If you have not exceeded your usage limits, you may be using a port that is not listed in the Allowed Referrers list. Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/places/auth

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got the message:

*Map.addControl is no longer supported in the Google Maps Javascript API v2. Please visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3 to migrate your application to v3.*

Perhaps that what you should do.